# Window resized when window is small and remains same even after window width is larger

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the ambiguous title, wasn't sure what should I use. I want to resize the player (Javascript) on the basis of the window size in an attempt to make it responsive. The standard width is `620px`, if the width is less than that I want that the width of the components should be `100%`. I have added a event listener using jQuery. But, the problem is that the player's components width becomes `100%` when the window size is less than 620, and it remains as 100% even if the window size becomes greater afterwards. Here is my code.

```
function resizeVideo() {
  var width = $('#slideshow').width();
    if(width < 620) {
      $('#object').width('100%');
      $('#object #background').width('100%');
      $('#object #slide_area').width('100%');
      $('#object #controls').width('100%');
      // alert("here");
    }
    else {

    }
  }
resizeVideo();
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeVideo, false);
```

Comment: why not resize back up to the original width in your else

Comment: You do not really expect an empty `else` branch to accomplish much, do you?

Comment: @Pete : This is weird. But, I figured it out myself. Please post the solution as an answer, and I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: doing the "#id #id" selector is a lot slower than just doing the second id by itself.

Comment: Reason: You never set it back to the size you want. You have an empty else where you need to reset the default. Best bet use a class and do not worry about resetting to the defaults. And with CSS Media queries, there is no need to even use JavaScript!

Comment: Sometimes you can't do without javascript... *#`£@ old browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resize back to your original width in your else statement (assuming you original width is 620:

```
function resizeVideo() {
   var width = $('#slideshow').width();
   if(width < 620) {
     $('#object').width('100%');
     $('#object #background').width('100%');
     $('#object #slide_area').width('100%');
     $('#object #controls').width('100%');
   } else {
     $('#object').width(620);
     $('#object #background').width(620);
     $('#object #slide_area').width(620);
     $('#object #controls').width(620);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just resize from the window width, not only from `#slideshow` :

```
function resizeVideo() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width < 620) {
        //Resize to 100%
        $('#object, #background, #slide_area, #controls').width('100%');
    } else {
        //Resize back to normal value
        $('#object, #background, #slide_area, #controls').width(620);
    }
}
```

As listener I'll do like that with jQuery :

```
$(window).on('resize', resizeVideo);
```